# PHP passing variables to external search form then display search result

Tags: php

I have a real estate property listing page containing the property address. I would like to show visitors the property's tax record from the county tax collector's public site.

The tax collector's site has 3 pages. First page has a search form where I would like to pass the property address from my site to the form. Then after clicking "submit", the second page displays the property's account number along with a "detail" button. Click on the "detail" button will take me to the third page where the tax record shows.

The 3rd page has the url "http://taxcollector.com/search_detail.asp?TaxYear=2012&Account=1234567".

Since all I have is the address, I wouldn't know what the account number is when I do the coding. How do I pass the address to the "external" search form, and then display the 3rd page?

I am not looking for someone to do the work for me, but I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. I was reading PHP-get, but I don't think it would do the job.

Update:

I don't plan to redirect the user to the 2nd page where he has to click on the detail button. I would like to have a "see tax record" button on my site, where the user can click to see the 3rd page, skipping the 2nd page. Sorry I should make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the DB or a source which you are using to display the house information, make a extra field/input for the houses account number, so when the user clicks "details" the needed information is already present all you need to do is a html markup of `<a href="site/details.asp/TaxYear=2012&Account=$HouseAccNo">`

Or any other method you are looking to direct the user to the site.

that's the way I'd do it, it will require a little more research but can get the job done

Comment: So you do not wish to direct the user to an external source rather show it on your page?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The answer is yes I do. It would be nice to direct the user to the last page which shows the tax record. I saw another website got it done like this.